# C++ find_if - How to find an ID (int(

Tags: c++, lambda

I wanted to find how to use find_if to find the SceneNode based on ID. I am unsure how to do this though.

I was able to for example, do this to remove the SceneNode based on the actual pointer like so:

```
SceneNode::Ptr SceneNode::detachChild(const SceneNode& node)
{
    auto found = std::find_if(mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(), [&](Ptr& p) -> bool {return p.get() == &node; });
    ...
```

but I am unsure on how to deal with find_if if I am looking for SceneNodes mID variable (which is an INT).

I.E.

```
SceneNode::Ptr SceneNode::findChild(int findID)
{
    auto found = std::find_if(mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(), ... ? = findID?; });
    ...
```

Does anyone have any good sites or info for me that explains find_if well? Thanks!

Comment: What's the declaration of `mChildren`? A container of some sort of smart pointer?

Comment: Why did you remove the lambda? You were so close... Just access the member with `.mID`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SceneNode::Ptr SceneNode::findChild(int findID)
{
    auto found = std::find_if(std::begin(mChildren), std::end(m_children),
        [=](Ptr& p) { return p->mID == findID; }
    );

    // ...
}
```

This lambda will capture `findID` by value and compare it with the `mID` member of what `Ptr` points to.

Comment: In the first example, it appears that `Ptr::get()` needs to be called in order to get an actual pointer...

Comment: If it's something like a `std::shared_ptr`, the `->` operator is overloaded. No need for `get()` in this case.

Comment: Good point. At least the repetition in these answers might be somewhat reassuring... :P

Comment: Yes, we're all on the same track. For the record, I was first. 8vD

Answer (score 1):

You basically had it...

```
auto found = std::find_if(
   mChildren.begin(),
   mChildren.end(),
   [&](Ptr& p) -> bool { return p->mID == node.mID; }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your first example, it appears that a `Ptr &` is the result of `mChildren.begin().operator*()` (or something compatible).

So:

```
SceneNode::Ptr SceneNode::findChild(int findID)
{
    auto found = std::find_if(
        mChildren.begin(), mChildren.end(),
        [findID](Ptr &ptr)
        {
            return findID == ptr.get()->mID;
        });

     ...
}
```